# ORACLE Data Provider for .net OREA -12154

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, database-connection

I am using Oracle data provider for .net to try to connect to the oracle DB, to add a ADO entity data framework model file, but i am getting the error below.
ORA-12154: TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified

when I try to tnsping the data source name that i provide in the VS dialog i can successfully resolve it to the correct ip and host names. But for some reason the Oracle Data provider doesn't seem to be reading it from from my C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
any ideas ?
i am using vs 2010 with the 32 bit oracle data provider from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

i can use the same TNS names on different sql client like sqlDbx it works smoothly on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a system environment variable TNS_ADMIN to the location of your tnsnames.ora file, does that help?